# Trouble building Skia on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, skia

I have followed the instructions given on how to build Skia on Mac.

[Instructions on building Skia on Mac](https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/user-documentation/quick-start-guides/mac)

However, I get the error:

> ninja: error:
>   '../../third_party/externals/libjpeg-turbo/simd/jccolor-sse2-64.asm', 
>   needed by 'gen/third_party/externals/libjpeg-turbo/jccolor-sse2-64.o',
>   missing and no known rule to make it
>           make: *** [most] Error 1

Here is what I did:

1. Installed Xcode
2. Installed depottools
3. Checked out Skia code via git
4. Run ./gyp_skia
5. ninja -C out/Debug dm

It fails on step 5.

Answer (score 0):

I did not follow the instructions as closely as I should have.

Checking out the Skia source is NOT simply git clone, but involves other steps!  Make sure you read the "Checkout the source code" link carefully.